# Transposing a 3D list in Python

Tags: python

I have to transpose a 3d list the following way:

Input:

```
matrix7 = [[['A ', 'E ', 'C#'], ['B ', 'E ', 'C#'], ['C ', 'E ', 'C#']], 
[['  ', 'F#', 'D '], ['  ', 'F#', 'D '], ['  ', 'F#', 'D ']], 
[['  ', 'E ', 'B '], ['  ', 'E ', 'B '], ['  ', 'E ', 'B ']], 
[['  ', 'E ', 'C#'], ['  ', 'E ', 'C#'], ['  ', 'E ', 'C#']], 
[['  ', 'F#', 'D '], ['  ', 'F#', 'D '], ['  ', 'F#', 'D ']], 
[['  ', 'E ', 'B '], ['  ', 'E ', 'B '], ['  ', 'E ', 'B ']], 
[['  ', '  ', '  '], ['  ', '  ', '  '], ['  ', '  ', '  ']], 
[['  ', 'E ', 'C#'], ['  ', 'E ', 'C#'], ['  ', 'E ', 'C#']]]
```

desired output:

```
[[['A ', 'E ', 'C#'], ['  ', 'F#', 'D '], ['  ', 'E ', 'B '], ['  ', 'E ', 'C#'], ['  ', 'F#', 'D '], ['  ', 'E ', 'B '], ['  ', '  ', '  '], ['  ', 'E ', 'C#']], 
[['B ', 'E ', 'C#'], ['  ', 'F#', 'D '], ['  ', 'E ', 'B '], ['  ', 'E ', 'C#'], 
['  ', 'F#', 'D '], ['  ', 'E ', 'B '], ['  ', '  ', '  '], ['  ', 'E ', 'C#']], 
[['C ', 'E ', 'C#'], ['  ', 'F#', 'D '], ['  ', 'E ', 'B '], ['  ', 'E ', 'C#'], 
['  ', 'F#', 'D '], ['  ', 'E ', 'B '], ['  ', '  ', '  '], ['  ', 'E ', 'C#']]]
```

I have the following program:

```
matrix8 = []
for index in matrix7:
    matrix8 = numpy.array(matrix7).transpose()
    matrix9 = matrix8.tolist()
print matrix9
```

which is giving me the wrong output:

```
[[['A ', 'E ', 'C#'], ['B ', 'E ', 'C#'], ['C ', 'E ', 'C#']], 
[['  ', 'F#', 'D '], ['  ', 'F#', 'D '], ['  ', 'F#', 'D ']], 
[['  ', 'E ', 'B '], ['  ', 'E ', 'B '], ['  ', 'E ', 'B ']], 
[['  ', 'E ', 'C#'], ['  ', 'E ', 'C#'], ['  ', 'E ', 'C#']], 
[['  ', 'F#', 'D '], ['  ', 'F#', 'D '], ['  ', 'F#', 'D ']], 
[['  ', 'E ', 'B '], ['  ', 'E ', 'B '], ['  ', 'E ', 'B ']], 
[['  ', '  ', '  '], ['  ', '  ', '  '], ['  ', '  ', '  ']], 
[['  ', 'E ', 'C#'], ['  ', 'E ', 'C#'], ['  ', 'E ', 'C#']]]
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: The code you've shown can't possibly work. You're creating an array of the entire 3D list for each of the top-level lists, instead creating a 2D array out of the sublist. And you're replacing `matrix9` each time through the loop, so all iterations of the loop but the last are meaningless. You're also calling `transpose` on a 3D `array`, which doesn't work the way you're expecting on a 3D array. (It just reverses the order of all 3 axes.)

Comment: Also, why are you converting back and forth between arrays and lists of lists? Why not just use a 3D array in the first place? You're making your code harder to understand, more verbose, and slower for no good reason.

Comment: @abarnert: [`numpy.ndarray.transpose`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.transpose.html) is a real method.

Comment: @user2357112: Sorry, botched edit. Of course it exists, but it doesn't transpose the first two axes, which is what the OP appears to want.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
numpy.transpose(matrix7, axes=(1, 0, 2)).tolist()  # The 'axes' attribute tells transpose to swaps axes 0 and 1, leaving the last one alone.
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
[[['A ', 'E ', 'C#'], ['  ', 'F#', 'D '], ['  ', 'E ', 'B '], ['  ', 'E ', 'C#'], ['  ', 'F#', 'D '], ['  ', 'E ', 'B '], ['  ', '  ', '  '], ['  ', 'E ', 'C#']],
[['B ', 'E ', 'C#'], ['  ', 'F#', 'D '], ['  ', 'E ', 'B '], ['  ', 'E ', 'C#'], ['  ', 'F#', 'D '], ['  ', 'E ', 'B '], ['  ', '  ', '  '], ['  ', 'E ', 'C#']],
[['C ', 'E ', 'C#'], ['  ', 'F#', 'D '], ['  ', 'E ', 'B '], ['  ', 'E ', 'C#'], ['  ', 'F#', 'D '], ['  ', 'E ', 'B '], ['  ', '  ', '  '], ['  ', 'E ', 'C#']]]
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't actually need numpy for this:

```
>>> [list(x) for x in zip(*matrix7)]
[[['A ', 'E ', 'C#'], ['  ', 'F#', 'D '], ['  ', 'E ', 'B '], ['  ', 'E ', 'C#'], ['  ', 'F#', 'D '], ['  ', 'E ', 'B '], ['  ', '  ', '  '], ['  ', 'E ', 'C#']],
 [['B ', 'E ', 'C#'], ['  ', 'F#', 'D '], ['  ', 'E ', 'B '], ['  ', 'E ', 'C#'], ['  ', 'F#', 'D '], ['  ', 'E ', 'B '], ['  ', '  ', '  '], ['  ', 'E ', 'C#']],
 [['C ', 'E ', 'C#'], ['  ', 'F#', 'D '], ['  ', 'E ', 'B '], ['  ', 'E ', 'C#'], ['  ', 'F#', 'D '], ['  ', 'E ', 'B '], ['  ', '  ', '  '], ['  ', 'E ', 'C#']]]
```

Or, if you don't mind getting a list of tuples of lists, just:

```
>>> list(zip(*matrix7))
[(['A ', 'E ', 'C#'], ['  ', 'F#', 'D '], ['  ', 'E ', 'B '], ['  ', 'E ', 'C#'], ['  ', 'F#', 'D '], ['  ', 'E ', 'B '], ['  ', '  ', '  '], ['  ', 'E ', 'C#']),
 (['B ', 'E ', 'C#'], ['  ', 'F#', 'D '], ['  ', 'E ', 'B '], ['  ', 'E ', 'C#'], ['  ', 'F#', 'D '], ['  ', 'E ', 'B '], ['  ', '  ', '  '], ['  ', 'E ', 'C#']),
 (['C ', 'E ', 'C#'], ['  ', 'F#', 'D '], ['  ', 'E ', 'B '], ['  ', 'E ', 'C#'], ['  ', 'F#', 'D '], ['  ', 'E ', 'B '], ['  ', '  ', '  '], ['  ', 'E ', 'C#'])]
```

Or, in Python 2.x, even less:

```
>>> zip(*matrix7)
[(['A ', 'E ', 'C#'], ['  ', 'F#', 'D '], ['  ', 'E ', 'B '], ['  ', 'E ', 'C#'], ['  ', 'F#', 'D '], ['  ', 'E ', 'B '], ['  ', '  ', '  '], ['  ', 'E ', 'C#']),
 (['B ', 'E ', 'C#'], ['  ', 'F#', 'D '], ['  ', 'E ', 'B '], ['  ', 'E ', 'C#'], ['  ', 'F#', 'D '], ['  ', 'E ', 'B '], ['  ', '  ', '  '], ['  ', 'E ', 'C#']),
 (['C ', 'E ', 'C#'], ['  ', 'F#', 'D '], ['  ', 'E ', 'B '], ['  ', 'E ', 'C#'], ['  ', 'F#', 'D '], ['  ', 'E ', 'B '], ['  ', '  ', '  '], ['  ', 'E ', 'C#'])]
```